# Rolling sum based on number of observations with start and end date of each roll in R

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I'm looking to capture both the running sum of team wins from their last 5 games using data.table frollsum(). That's easy enough, but I also want to capture the start date and end date of each rollling 5 games in their own columns so I can identify the date range of each roll.

Here's a dput for just a quick sample to work with. The "first" and "last" cols in summarize don't know to use the roll and uses all the data so it doesn't capture what I'm hoping for.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19655, 19655, 19657, 19657, 
19658, 19658, 19660, 19660, 19662, 19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 
19666, 19667, 19667), class = "Date"), team = c("Detroit Pistons", 
"Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", 
"Chicago Bulls", "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Detroit Pistons", 
"Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls", "Chicago Bulls", 
"Detroit Pistons", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls"), result = c("lose", 
"lose", "win", "win", "win", "lose", "win", "lose", "lose", "lose", 
"lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "win")), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000015d477c5930>, row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")

df |>
  group_by(team) |> 
  summarise(roll_wins_fifty = frollsum(result == "win", n = 5),
  first = first(date),
  last = last(date))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for: we can print the `first` and `last` observation date of each froll result using just the actual `date` (for `last`) and its lagged by `n = 4` values (for `first`). The result looks good to me, but we'd need to test it on a bit dirtier data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df |>
  arrange(team) |> # for better printing
  group_by(team) |> 
  mutate(roll_wins_fifty = frollsum(result == "win", n = 5),
         last = date,
         first = lag(date, n = 4)
         )
#> # A tibble: 16 × 6
#> # Groups:   team [2]
#>    date       team            result roll_wins_fifty last       first     
#>    <date>     <chr>           <chr>            <dbl> <date>     <date>    
#>  1 2023-10-25 Chicago Bulls   lose                NA 2023-10-25 NA        
#>  2 2023-10-27 Chicago Bulls   win                 NA 2023-10-27 NA        
#>  3 2023-10-28 Chicago Bulls   lose                NA 2023-10-28 NA        
#>  4 2023-10-30 Chicago Bulls   win                 NA 2023-10-30 NA        
#>  5 2023-11-01 Chicago Bulls   lose                 2 2023-11-01 2023-10-25
#>  6 2023-11-03 Chicago Bulls   lose                 2 2023-11-03 2023-10-27
#>  7 2023-11-04 Chicago Bulls   lose                 1 2023-11-04 2023-10-28
#>  8 2023-11-06 Chicago Bulls   win                  2 2023-11-06 2023-10-30
#>  9 2023-10-25 Detroit Pistons lose                NA 2023-10-25 NA        
#> 10 2023-10-27 Detroit Pistons win                 NA 2023-10-27 NA        
#> 11 2023-10-28 Detroit Pistons win                 NA 2023-10-28 NA        
#> 12 2023-10-30 Detroit Pistons lose                NA 2023-10-30 NA        
#> 13 2023-11-01 Detroit Pistons lose                 2 2023-11-01 2023-10-25
#> 14 2023-11-02 Detroit Pistons lose                 2 2023-11-02 2023-10-27
#> 15 2023-11-05 Detroit Pistons lose                 1 2023-11-05 2023-10-28
#> 16 2023-11-06 Detroit Pistons lose                 0 2023-11-06 2023-10-30
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19655, 19655, 19657, 19657, 
                                        19658, 19658, 19660, 19660, 19662, 19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 
                                        19666, 19667, 19667), class = "Date"),
                     team = c("Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons",
                              "Chicago Bulls", "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Detroit Pistons", 
                              "Chicago Bulls", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls", "Chicago Bulls", 
                              "Detroit Pistons", "Detroit Pistons", "Chicago Bulls"),
                     result = c("lose", "lose", "win", "win", "win", "lose", "win", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "win")),
                row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Note that if your data is huge you may benefit from dcast+frollsum(.SD)+melt so frollsum computes groups (columns after dcast) in parallel

Comment: And please don't load tidyverse when you use only dplyr. It is a bad practice to demand from users much more than actually needed.